# Aminium/Ammonium?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, ions, amines, nitrogen

[image]

Chemdraw names this as 2-carboxyethan-1-aminium. Shouldn't it be ammonium? What's an aminium ion?

Comment: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00277, https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P6.html#62

Comment: @andselisk I have seen this, but unfortunately it provides no information on aminium ions for me to understand.

Comment: "*Aminium*" is the cationic suffix for the parent neutral [amine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amine) group $\ce{R-NH2}$. There is no ammonium/ammonia present in your structure.

Comment: But it's a substituted ammonium ion. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium This wiki page says that substituted ammonium ions in IUPAC nomenclature are called aminium ions. Ir then gives an example forming dimethylammonium ion by protonation of dimethylamine.

Comment: "*Substituted ammonium ion*" **is** *amine*. The cationic form of β‐alanine you have drawn is an *amino* acid, not *ammono* acid.

Comment: For example, we have H3CNH3+. It's called methanaminium. But why is (CH3CH3)NH2+ called dimethylammonium while it's from a secondary amine?

Comment: No, $\ce{Me2NH2+}$ is **dimethylazanium**. According to IUPAC, the names stemming from ‘ammonium’ are only for *quaternary* salts.

Comment: Then what is (CH3)3NH+ and (CH3)4N+ called respectively. The second one tetramethylammonium? And the first one?

Comment: PINs for $\ce{Me3NH+}$ and $\ce{Me4N+}$ are **trimethylazanium** and, yes, **tetramethylammonium**, respectively. Casually you can see and informally use trimethylammonium for $\ce{Me3NH+}$ too, but that name wouldn't be the preferred IUPAC one which ChemDraw usually tries to produce.